# Append row to csv file Ruby 1.9 CSV lib

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-1.9

Using Ruby 1.9 and CSV lib, I can't seem to append a row.  The example in the documentation opens the file, and overwrites the row. What is the correct way to append rows to the document?

Example from documentation:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 48):

I think you can change the open to use `ab`:

```
CSV.open("t.csv", "ab") do |csv|
```

Answer (score 13):

I will usually use the following to write to a csv file (Or any file)

```
File.open("filename", 'a+') {|f| f.write("datatowrite\n)}
```

Comment: Note that 'a+' is for read *and* [write/append](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_io.html). If you only need to append, then 'a' is sufficient. You can also use [File::APPEND](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_file.html), possibly in combination with other mode settings.

Comment: We should always use a+ because it will create file if not exists.

Comment: See [What are the Ruby File.open modes and options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682359/what-are-the-ruby-file-open-modes-and-options)

Answer (score 2):

```
File.open('filename', 'a'){ |outfile|
  CSV::Writer.generate(outfile) do |csv|
    csv << ['c1', nil, '', '"', "\r\n", 'c2']
  end
}
```

Comment: AFAIK CSV::Writer is [not available in ruby 1.9](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2140482/514483)