# How do I create a copy of some columns of a CSV file in Ruby with different data in one column?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file called "A.csv". I need to generate a new CSV file called "B.csv" with data from "A.csv".

I will be using a subset of columns from "A.csv" and will have to update one column's values to new values in "B.csv". Ultimately, I will use this data from B.csv to validate against a database.

1. How do I create a new CSV file?
2. How do I copy the required columns' data from A.csv to "B.csv"?
3. How do I append values for a particular column?

I am new to Ruby, but I am able to read CSV to get an array or hash.

Comment: This is lacking basic information, such as showing us your effort toward solving the problem. This information is in the CSV documentation. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output array to CSV in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822422/output-array-to-csv-in-ruby)

Answer (score 193):

As mikeb pointed out, there are the docs - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html - Or you can follow along with the examples below (all are tested and working):

### To create a new file:

In this file we'll have two rows, a header row and data row, very simple CSV:

```
require "csv"
CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["animal", "count", "price"]
  csv << ["fox", "1", "$90.00"]
end
```

result, a file called "file.csv" with the following:

```
animal,count,price
fox,1,$90.00
```

---

### How to append data to a CSV

Almost the same formula as above only instead of using "wb" mode, we'll use "a+" mode. For more information on these see this stack overflow answer: [What are the Ruby File.open modes and options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682359/what-are-the-ruby-file-open-modes-and-options)

```
CSV.open("file.csv", "a+") do |csv|
  csv << ["cow", "3","2500"]
end
```

Now when we open our file.csv we have:

```
animal,count,price
fox,1,$90.00
cow,3,2500
```

---

### Read from our CSV file

Now you know how to copy and to write to a file, to read a CSV and therefore grab the data for manipulation you just do:

```
CSV.foreach("file.csv") do |row|
  puts row #first row would be ["animal", "count", "price"] - etc.
end
```

Of course, this is like one of like a hundred different ways you can pull info from a CSV using this gem. For more info, I suggest visiting the docs now that you have a primer: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: What if I want to open without writing to right away? Just don't use the block?

Comment: thanks for the copy & paste able code! - too lazy to write it.

Comment: This covers creating a new CSV, but then goes into information about adding and reading whole rows rather than addressing the request to copy a subset of the available coumns and either alter or add to their values. I have the same sort of project as the OP and wasn't helped by the documentation or this answer, so hopefully I can come back here to provide a more specific answer once I figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen Ruby's CSV class? It seems pretty comprehensive. Check it out here:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: thanks for the link. I would be referring it. Can I edit the csv file through ruby? I mean can I update a column values in csv ? later get hash of only required columns?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use `CSV::parse` to help Ruby understand your CSV as the table of data that it is and enable easy access to values by header.

Unfortunately, the available [documentation on the `CSV::parse` method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse) doesn't make it very clear how to actually use it for this purpose.

I had a similar task and was helped much more by *[How to Read & Parse CSV Files With Ruby](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/parse-csv-ruby/)* on rubyguides.com than by the CSV class documentation or by the answers pointing to it from here.

I recommend reading that page in its entirety. The crucial part is about transforming a given CSV into a `CSV::Table` object using:

```
table = CSV.parse(File.read("cats.csv"), headers: true)
```

Now there's [documentation on the `CSV::Table` class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html), but again you might be helped more by the clear examples on the rubyguides.com page. One thing I'll highlight is that when you tell `.parse` to expect headers, the resulting table will treat the first row of data as row `[0]`.

You will probably be especially interested in the `.by_col` method available for your new `Table` object. This will allow you to iterate through different column index positions in the input and/or output and either copy from one to the other or add a new value to the output. If I get it working, I'll come back and post an example.