# Ruby - write a CSV object to a file in 1 line of code

Tags: ruby, csv

I've got this bit of code:

```
presorted_csv = CSV.read 'out.csv'
presorted_csv.sort! { |a, b| a[0].to_i <=> b[0].to_i }
```

I'm now wanting to simply write the sorted CSV file to disk.
I'd expect it to be something like:

```
CSV.write('new.csv', presorted_csv)
```

however while there's a `read` method:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read

there's no `write` method!

How do I do this in 1 line of code?

Comment: There is. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-To+a+File - open the file and write

Comment: No, that opens the file and gives you a handle to write rows to the file. I've already got a handle. I simply want to write to the file in 1 line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a new CSV file in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718872/how-do-i-create-a-new-csv-file-in-ruby)

Comment: Tip: `sort_by! { |v| v[0].to_i }` would be more succinct.

Comment: Please edit to show the value of `presorted_csv` (pared down if necessary, but complete). Those giving answers can then use that information to show calculations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland is that really necessary?! The line of code `presorted_csv = CSV.read 'out.csv'` should be sufficient. It's a simple CSV file like: 'a,b,c,d'.