# Ruby CSV - Create a file and edit a file in one .rb and then open and edit it starting where the last .rb left off in another .rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I was using

```
CSV.open(filename, "w") do |csv|
```

to create and write to a file in one ruby.rb file and now I need to open it and edit it in a second .rb file. I need the new file to start writing new rows where the first edit ended.

Any good way to do this? Calling

```
CSV.open(filename, "w") do |csv|
```

again overwrites the line that were already written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of the `open` method is the write mode.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17866433/9595653

And also refer to the documentation for `CSV` here:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

You will want to change the option to `"a"`

Comment: Yup! There it is. Thank you. Answer accepted.