# How to stop Ruby automatically adding carriage returns

Tags: ruby, linux, windows

I am having problems constructing text files from a Windows machine to be read on a Linux environment.

```
def test

    my_file = Tempfile.new('filetemp.txt')

    my_file.print "This is on the first line"
    my_file.print "\x0A"
    my_file.print "This is on the second line"

    my_file.close

    FileUtils.mv(my_file.path, "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Folder/test.usr")

end
```

`0A`is the ASCII code for  line feed, yet when I open the resulting file in Notepad++, I see it has appended CR *and* LF on the end of the line.

How do I add *only* a Line Feed as the new line character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the file in binary mode causes Ruby to 'suppress EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows' (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682359/what-are-the-ruby-file-open-modes-and-options)).

The problem is that [Tempfiles are automatically opened in `w+` mode](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-new). I couldn't find a way to change this on creation of the Tempfile.

The answer is to change it after creation using `binmode`:

```
def test


    my_file = Tempfile.new('filetemp.txt')
    my_file.binmode 

    my_file.print "This is on the first line"
    my_file.print "\x0A"    # \n now also works as a newline character
    my_file.print "This is on the second line"

    my_file.close

    FileUtils.mv(my_file.path, "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Folder/test.usr")

end
```

Answer (score 3):

try setting the output separator `$\` to `\n`.

```
def test
    $\ = "\n"
    my_file = Tempfile.new('filetemp.txt')

    my_file.print "This is on the first line"
    my_file.print "This is on the second line"

    my_file.close

    FileUtils.mv(my_file.path, "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Folder/test.usr")

end
```

or you should be able to use `#write` which will not add the output separator

```
def test
    my_file = Tempfile.new('filetemp.txt')

    my_file.write "This is on the first line"
    my_file.write "\x0A"
    my_file.write "This is on the second line"

    my_file.close

    FileUtils.mv(my_file.path, "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Folder/test.usr")

end
```

Comment: This still gives me the same issue - the problem seems to be the way in which "\n" is interpreted in a Windows environment. It's trying to be a bit too clever I think

Comment: Are you Touching the file with a windows program after ruby?  How are you getting the files to the Linux machine

Comment: Currently I'm not moving it anywhere, merely opening it on my Windows machine to check the line endings. I've managed to solve the problem however - I'll post it in an answer shortly