# ActiveRecord: Rip out and name an image from a mediumblob in the database

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

In the database I have the table `users`. This table has the column `mugshot` which is of type `mediumblob`.  I know that this mediumblob's content type is `image/jpeg`.

What I want to do is write a ruby script that requires in ActiveRecord, and does the following:

- iterate through all the records within the `users` table
- Create a `.jpg` file from the data within that mediumblob field
- name the file according to other columns on the `users` table. Example: "#{user.first_name}_#{user.last_name}.jpg".

The part I am having trouble figuring out is how to rip out the image from that `mediumblob` field and then name the file what I want:

```
User.all.each do |user|
 # rip out the image from the mediumblob field
 # save the file as "#{user.first_name}_#{userlast_name}.jpg"
 # save the file within the folder 'my_images' located on the Desktop
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  File.open("#{user.first_name}_#{user.last_name}.jpg", 'wb') do |file|
    file << user.mugshot
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks great!  Just one quick question: What does the 'wb' argument mean?  Would it still work if I just said 'w+' instead?

Comment: You can find the different modes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682359/what-are-the-ruby-file-open-modes-and-options

I don't think you need the ```+``` in your use case.