# Ruby: Add line in file

Tags: ruby, file

I have a file in which one I want to store some datas.

Using IRB, I can add different lines in the file. However, using a Ruby script writen in a file, I have issues.

I can write a line, it is stored as it should be, but when I re launch the script and re use the method, it overwrites what was in the file instead of adding content at the next line.

```
def create_new_account
    puts "Set the account's name"
    @account_name = gets
    puts "New account's name: #{@account_name}
    open("accounts.txt","w+") do |account_file|
        account_file.write "ac;#{@account_name}\n"

    end
end
```

I had a look to the different parameters of the method `open`, but seems like it's not there.
Moreover, I tried `puts` instead of `write`, but there is no difference, always the same problem.

Could someone help me understand what is wrong with the code?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682359/what-are-the-ruby-file-open-modes-and-options   but as stated you need append

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file in [**append** mode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) like so

```
open('accounts.txt', 'a+')
```

otherwise the file is opened so as to overwrite the existing data.

> "a" - Write-only, each write call appends data at end of file.
>        Creates a new file for writing if file does not exist.