# Saving a file to .xml format in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code:

```
 File.open(“MIO.TA.1234567.#{Time.now.strftime(“%F”)}.{Time.now.strftime  
 (“%T”)}.xml”, “w”) { |file| file.write(xml) }
```

The only requirement is to be able to save to MIO.TA.1234567.20180309.090000.xml instead of having to have output.xml existing and me having to open to write.

Comment: What is `xml` in `file.write(xml)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you're already doing is correct**.

The file you name doesn't need to already exist, and the first argument of `File.open` will take the path to a file, so you can write anywhere you like.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682359/what-are-the-ruby-file-open-modes-and-options) for reference.

Comment: I have just realized this, I have tried to now change the file naming convention like so: 

     File.open(“MIO.TA.1234567.#{Time.now.strftime(“%F”)}.   
     {Time.now.strftime(“%T”)}.xml”, “w”) { |file| file.write(xml) }

This produces an error: syntax error unexpected ,

Comment: It's possibly because of the missing # character for your second `Time` call, which means your quotes are messing up the overall string.